# List all users email in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to list All registerd users email and CompanyName, I have 3 registered users, but in my case it shows only current user email and company name:

[image]
[image]
This is .js file, in clien:

```
Template.homepage.helpers({
    user: function(){
        return Meteor.users.find();
    }
});

Template.homepage.helpers({
    userEmail: function(){
        return this.emails[0].address;
    }
});
```

And this is html file:

```
<div class="row text-center">
        {{ #each user }}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="..." alt="">
                <p><strong>{{userEmail}}</strong></p>
                <p>{{profile.companyName}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/each }}
    </div>
```

Why it does not show other users email and CompanyName? Where is my mistake, can you help me with this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do all of them have ``email`` and ``companyName`` fields and if so, do you publish all the necessary fields of all users?

Comment: You have to publish the emails in order to do that, which is a very bad idea for user rights due to vulnerability by scam. Also I doubt the companyName field exists for the 3rd user. 'profile' field should be published by default. I think you didn't publish or subscribe any user data at all.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you can check two things.

First is if all users have the same data on its documents. On your printscreen, only first user have an email. Second one dont even have a profile item, and third one dont have an email.

If it is OK and all users have all fields on database, then probably you should `Publish` that data from server and `Subscribe` to that content. By default (if `insecure` and `autopublish` packages are already removed), `Meteor` publishes only your own user data, and not others data.

So you would need to add on `server` something like this:

```
 Meteor.publish("allusers", function () {
      if (!this.userId) {
           // this will make this available just to logged in users, and not for everyone.
           this.ready();
           return;
      }
      return Meteor.users.find({},{
          fields: {
              // here you can hide some of the data to be published. 
              //'0' means that that information will not be published to client.
              // you can also change to '1' instead of '0'. Then instead of hiding some
              // data, you would just show those listed.
              'services': 0,
              'createdAt': 0,
              'username': 0, //as you want emails, so you should hide this one.
              'profile.birthday': 0,
              'profile.activationcode': 0
          }
     });
});
```

Finally, on client, you should subscribe to that publishing on pages you will need it. I do not know your application and what is will be used for, but it is recommended to hide user data from public access. Publishing that content should be done only on safe places. That is why I have left there that code for publishing only for logged in users.